# Don't want errors if Cookies are not set

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, cookies

[CoffeeNoticeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry7Tj.png)

OK I tried to look through possible duplicates but didn't help

Now , I have a coffee website mainly built in HTML 4 and CSS3, JavaScript and a bit of php. What I did is on a page named `coffee.html` I created a picture. When I click on it a `cookie` is created.

I have `8` such images on one page like `coffee.html` and I have `4` such pages.

That means I can create `8 x 4 = 32 cookies`.

On orders page where I can see what are the items I ordered.
I used

```
<?php 
    if($_COOKIE['cup1'])
        {echo "<img src='img//coffee69.png' width='10%' onClick='erasec1()'>";} 

    if($_COOKIE['cup2'])
        {echo "<img src='img//coffee131.png' width='10%'>";} 
    if($_COOKIE['cup3'])
        {echo "<img src='img//hot drink64.png' width='10%'>";} 
    if($_COOKIE['cup4'])
        {echo "<img src='img//caffeine1.png' width='10%'>";}

    if($_COOKIE['cup5'])
        {echo "<img src='img//tea24.png' width='10%' onClick='erasec1()'>";} 
    if($_COOKIE['cup6'])
        {echo "<img src='img//coffee20.png' width='10%'>";} 
    if($_COOKIE['cup7'])
        {echo "<img src='img//cup31.png' width='10%'>";} 
    if($_COOKIE['cup8'])
        {echo "<img src='img//coffee34.png' width='10%'>";}

 ?>
```

This is only for first 8 cookies. like that I will have 24 more cookies.
So my Question is

From the start I don't have something set for those cookies
and that's why it shows error messages `ugly error messages`

> Notice: Undefined index: cup1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cafe/orders.php on line 56`

and that sucks.

I will leave a few screen shots to go through. and a download link for my code.

## UPDATE

[Links to webpage](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5fMAOkkUCx-SW53QXIxYzU3X0E/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [isset()](http://php.net/isset) function to check cookie set or not.

```html
<?php 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cup1']))
        {echo "<img src='img//coffee69.png' width='10%' onClick='erasec1()'>";} 

    if(isset($_COOKIE['cup2']))
        {echo "<img src='img//coffee131.png' width='10%'>";} 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cup3']))
        {echo "<img src='img//hot drink64.png' width='10%'>";} 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cup4']))
        {echo "<img src='img//caffeine1.png' width='10%'>";}

    if(isset($_COOKIE['cup5']))
        {echo "<img src='img//tea24.png' width='10%' onClick='erasec1()'>";} 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cup6']))
        {echo "<img src='img//coffee20.png' width='10%'>";} 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cup7']))
        {echo "<img src='img//cup31.png' width='10%'>";} 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cup8']))
        {echo "<img src='img//coffee34.png' width='10%'>";}

 ?>
```

Comment: Thankx Guy I have just posted a link to the website plz check it out..and Yes THE isset() function solves it...CHEERS

Comment: @xuki-team glad to know your problem is solve good work Smit.

Answer (score 2):

How about storing one single cookie instead? You're essentially storing a series of booleans, which can easily be compressed into a single number.

```
<?php

$images = [
    'coffee69.png', // 0
    'coffee70.png', // 1
    'coffee80.png', // 2
    'tea96.png',    // 3
    'milk34.png',   // 4
    'cola53.png',   // 5
    'etc.png',      // 6
    'more.png'      // 7
];

$number = get(3) | get(5) | get(6); //get me some tea, cola, and etc.

echo $number . "\n\n"; //echos 104

rtn($images, $number);

/* Functions */

function get($num) {
    return pow(2, $num);
}

function rtn($images, $num) {
    $size = sizeof($images);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
        if ($num & get($i))
            echo '<img src="img/' . $images[$i] . '" width="10%">' . "\n";
}
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/6af2e94126a42c):

```
104

<img src="img/tea96.png" width="10%">
<img src="img/cola53.png" width="10%">
<img src="img/etc.png" width="10%">
```

So when you're deciding what cookie to set on the JavaScript side, you can simply use this function to generate your number:

```js
function get(num) {
  return Math.pow(2, num);
}

alert(get(3) | get(5) | get(6)); //echos 104
```

So now you can simply set your cookie to 104 (or whatever output it gives you) with:

```
document.cookie.coffee = 104;
```

Now within PHP, you only need to check one cookie:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['coffee'])) {
    $coffee = $_COOKIE['coffee'];

    //and coffee now is some number that can be process with:

    rtn($images, $coffee); //check the above code for reference

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use isset statement. It might help. `<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['cup1'])){ echo '<img'; } if (!(isset($_COOKIE['cup1']))){ echo '<img src=\'noimage.jpg\'>'; } ?>`

Answer (score 1):

**From your question:**

> From the start I don't have something set for those cookies

Yes you need to use `isset()` for checking either `COOKIE` set or not.

**Example:**

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cup1'])) {
     echo "<img src='img//coffee69.png' width='10%' onClick='erasec1()'>";
} 

if(isset($_COOKIE['cup2'])) {
........
```